# Configure Django's builtin authentication to use a different template folder other than "registration"

Tags: django, django-authentication

When using Django's built-in authentication mechanism, how can I configure it to look for template pages like login.html in a different directory besides "registration"?

Comment: All the [auth views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views) take a `template_name` parameter, which can point wherever you like.

Comment: I'd normally like to have a single point where I can say template_dir = 'auth' but since there's a limited amount really of possible templates for the auth contrib, I think this would be ok. It's not ideal but might be the best for now.

Comment: If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py), the default is set individually that's why you have to change the template_name for each view you want to use

Answer (score 0):

1.) Use class-based views
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/

2.) Get data from parent views,

```
from allauth.account.views import LoginView, SignupView
```

3.) replace in views.py the template path with your own

4.) Use your views in urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', MyLoginView.as_view(), name="custom_login"),
    path('signup/', MySignupView.as_view(), name="custom_singup"),
]
```